# Persist HashMap in ORMLite

Tags: java, android, orm, hashmap, ormlite

Im using ORMLite in my Android app. I need to persist this class, which has a HashMap. What is a good way of persisting it? Its my first time trying to persist a HashMap, also first time with ORMLite so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

****Edit****
If that makes any difference, the Exercise class is simply a String (that also works as id in the database), and the Set class has an int id (which is also id in database), int weight and int reps.

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Workout {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
    Date created;

    /*
     * The hashmap needs to be persisted somehow
     */
    HashMap<Exercise, ArrayList<Set>> workoutMap;

    public Workout() {          
    }
    public Workout(HashMap<Exercise, ArrayList<Set>> workoutMap, Date created){
        this.workoutMap = workoutMap;
        this.created = created;
    }

    public void addExercise(Exercise e, ArrayList<Set> setList) {
        workoutMap.put(e, setList);
    }
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wow.  Persisting a `HashMap` whose value is a `List` of `Set`s.  Impressive.

So in [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) you can persist any `Serializable` field.   Here's the documentation about the type and how you have to configure it:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/serializable

So your field would look something like:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
Map<Exercise, List<Set>> workoutMap;
```

*Please note* that if the map is at all large then this will most likely not be very performant.  Also, your `Exercise` class (and the `List` and `Set` classes) need to implement `Serializable`.

If you need to search this map, you might consider storing the values in the `Set` in another table in which case you might want to take a look at how ORMLite persists ["foreign objects"](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-object).

Comment: Sir, you are a hero. Thank you so much! For the record, I also needed to add "implements Serializable" to the Exercise and Set classes.

Comment: Hello Gray, I have a question related to persisting Maps: As far as I am aware of, only Collections are supported in ormlite for persistence, together with foreigncollections - or am I mixing something up here?

Comment: Ask the question on the mailing list @Ready4Android.  You are right though.  http://groups.google.com/group/ormlite-user