# Persisting a Map<String,String> in ORMLite without resorting to DataType.SERIALIZABLE?

Tags: java, orm, ormlite

I've got a relatively simple class that is primarily backed by a `Map<String,String>`.  I'd like to persist this class and be able search within the keys within the map.  Based on this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155923/persist-hashmap-in-ormlite) I get the feeling that Maps can only be persisted as a serialized blob.

I also see on the [ORMLite website](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#SEC30) the following:

```
public class Account {
    …
    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    ForeignCollection<Order> orders;
    …
}
```

> In the above example, the @ForeignCollectionField annotation marks
>   that the orders field is a collection of the orders that match the
>   account. The field type of orders must be either ForeignCollection
>   or `Collection<T>` - no other collections are supported. The
>   @ForeignCollectionField annotation supports the following fields:

Based on the above I get the impression that what I want isn't possible, but I thought I'd check here to be sure.  I have it persisted in Hibernate, but I'd rather use something lighter like ORMLite!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, there is no way in [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) to persist a `Map`.  Keeping with the KISS principle, only the simple `Collection` class is supported.  `Set` and `Map` have a lot more interface weight to them and will probably never be supported.

I don't have any super great work arounds for you.  You could obviously use `ForeignCollection` and then have a local `Map` field that you create when you need to access the collection that way.  Maybe an `addOrder()` method that would add it to the `ForeignCollection` and the `Map`.

Comment: Gray, thanks for the advice, and thanks for the great work on ORMLite.

Comment: Thanks @Jason.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 4):

One pretty easy solution is to have the getters and setters work with a JSONObject behind the scenes, and putting that object as a String in the database.

But then again, JSON isn't part of java-out-of-the-box so this may feel unneccesary if you're not using it anyway.